# How to make proper length of serach bar in angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design

[Help me to make search bar shown in given image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bfpF.png)

Comment: can you share what you have tried on stackblitz or on some platform like that.

Comment: code reference ?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
            <form fxLayoutAlign="center center" fxFlex fxHide.xs>
                <mat-form-field class="search" fxFlex="50" [floatPlaceholder]="'never'">
                    <input matInput name="search" placeholder="Search" [(ngModel)]="search" />
                    <button mat-button color="primary" *ngIf="isSearchIcon" type="submit" matSuffix mat-icon-button aria-label="Clear" (click)="searchSomething()">
                        <mat-icon>search</mat-icon>
                    </button>
                    <button mat-button color="accent" *ngIf="isClearIcon" (click)="clearSearch()" matSuffix mat-icon-button aria-label="Clear">
                        <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
                    </button>
                </mat-form-field>
            </form>
```